# Hive - partition by year

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hql, hive

I am partitioning by year in hive. I have created a script:

```
DROP TABLE movies_byYear;

CREATE TABLE movies_byYear (title STRING, full_name STRING, ep_name STRING, type STRING, ep_num STRING, suspended BOOLEAN) PARTITIONED BY (year INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE movies_byYear PARTITION (year='2013') SELECT title, full_name, ep_name, type, ep_num, suspended FROM movies WHERE year='2013';
```

However, when using: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movies WHERE year='2013';`

I do not get all movies by year 2013 back, instead I get all movies back.

Is it also possible to let hive decide where to partition?

I really appreciate your answer!!!

**UPDATE**

When adding `year` I get:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE movies_byYear PARTITION (year=2013) SELECT title, full_name, ep_name, type, ep_num, suspended, year FROM movies WHERE year=2013;

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10044]: Line 1:23 Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different '2013': Table insclause-0 has 6 columns, but query has 7 columns.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When inserting, you insert:

```
SELECT title, full_name, ep_name, type, ep_num, suspended
```

Add year to that... Currently your `year` field in movies_byYear is null...

When you specify partition by `year` in your create table statement in hive, `year` will be a column in the table!!!

**UPDATE**

Replace this

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE movies_byYear PARTITION (year='2013') SELECT title, full_name, ep_name, type, ep_num, suspended FROM movies WHERE year='2013';`

with this:

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE movies_byYear PARTITION (year=2013) SELECT title, full_name, ep_name, type, ep_num, suspended FROM movies WHERE year='2013';`

Namely, remove the single quotes around the year value in Partition...

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, it is not working... Please see my update! btw is it also possible to just let hive choose the partitioning?

Comment: You are specifying year as INT and then using Year='2013' (STRING)...
Try changing: PARTITION (year='2013') to PARTITION (year=2013)

Comment: Thx for your answer! However, I do not get it. In my update I didn`t used `'...'`